# Did JFK call himself a jelly donut in his famous Berlin speech?

Tags: quotes, jfk

This morning, in an attempt to find inspiration for a name for my new puppy (who is a great talker), I googled "great orators". The [second hit took me here](https://www.eaglestalent.com/blog/top-10-greatest-orators), where JFK is again listed as one of history's great orators. However, I was surprised to read,

> Perhaps President’s Kennedy’s finest oration moment was his *Ich Bin Ein Berliner* speech – a notable moment of the Cold War. Delivered in front of the Berlin Wall in 1963, the speech provided a morale boost for West Berliners who feared an imminent East German occupation.
>
> “Two thousand years ago the proudest boast was civis Romanus sum [I am a Roman citizen]. Today, in the world of freedom, the proudest boast is ‘Ich bin ein Berliner!’… All free men, wherever they may live, are citizens of Berlin, and, therefore, as a free man, I take pride in the words ‘Ich bin ein Berliner!’
>
> Okay, so technical speaking what JFK told those German’s that summer day nearly 50 years ago actually meant: “I am a Jelly Donut” (No kidding, look it up). However, the crowd understood what the young president was speaking about and so did the Soviet Union.

There is a jelly donut called a *Berliner* in English.

Did the crowd think JFK said he (was) a jelly donut, and did they laugh?

Comment: Berliner also (and within the context probably almost exlusively) means someone from/belonging to Berlin. The source seems a bit unclear about the misunderstanding. What is meant by "technically speaking" and "the crowd understood"? Maybe the source is not a very good one.

Comment: Only to the same extent that Richard Nixon called himself a penis when he called himself "Dick".

Comment: What's a JFK? ..

Comment: @MaskedMan [Jakob Forsbacka-Karlsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Forsbacka-Karlsson)

Comment: @MaskedMan - President Kennedy, John Fitzgerald (JFK).

Comment: @medica So mention that in the question. USA is not the only country in the world that has a President, and JFK is not some universal acronym.

Comment: @MaskedMan - Can you name me another country which had a President Kennedy (first line of quote)?

Comment: @medica That is not relevant. Your question should contain all the required details, the readers shouldn't have to go searching for the information. Remember you write the question only once, but it will be read by hundreds or thousands of users. A few seconds of time you spend adding the relevant details, will save several hours of (cumulative) effort for the others. Your claim that a few seconds of your time are more precious than the time spent by thousands of users to figure out what you are talking about is at best uncharitable.

Comment: @MaskedMan - "Your claim that a few seconds of your time are more precious than the time spent by thousands of users to figure out what you are talking about is at best uncharitable." Um... that's baffling. I never made that claim. If one of us is uncharitable, I don't think it's me.

Comment: JFK is an abbrevation many understand correctly, at least in Hungary and probably in Europe too. Scource: personal experience in, among others, local media.

Comment: I hope you decided to name the puppy "Berliner".

Comment: "USA is not the only country in the world that has a President" It is the one that is most obviously the one being discussed. How many other English-speaking counties are there with a president? What's next, are you going to complain about someone calling the US "America", since it's not the only county in the Americas?

Comment: "JFK is not some universal acronym." What do you mean be "universal"? It certainly is something that I would expect any reasonably educated person to be familiar with, and if someone is so unfamiliar with US history as to not know what it referred to, then why should the OP expect them to know who John F. Kennedy is? This is a Skeptics site, not Give Everyone a Crash Course on US History site. Should they also explain what the Berlin Wall was?

Comment: "Your question should contain all the required details" Required details? All you *need* to know to answer this question is to know what "berliner" means. Everything else is just unnecessary background. "A few seconds of time you spend adding the relevant details" They included a link that says who JFK is.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

No, it wasn't interpreted that way.  Berliner is a name for a doughnut, similar to a Frankfurter being a type of sausage.  However, it does also mean living in/being from Berlin, similar to Londoner.

See this article, [The Real Meaning of Ich Bin ein Berliner](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2013/08/the-real-meaning-of-ich-bin-ein-berliner/309500/), as told by the director of the John F. Kennedy Presidential Library and Museum:

> Afterward it would be suggested that Kennedy had got the translation
>   wrong—that by using the article ein before the word Berliner, he had
>   mistakenly called himself a jelly doughnut. In fact, Kennedy was
>   correct. To state Ich bin Berliner would have suggested being born in
>   Berlin, whereas adding the word ein implied being a Berliner in
>   spirit. His audience understood that he meant to show his solidarity.

Comment: So, out of curiosity, what does a person from Frankfurt call themselves?

Comment: @mickburkejnr: Frankfurter, just like Berliner and Hamburger. See this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_cities)

Comment: @EricDuminil Thought it would be, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: "Ich bin Berliner would have suggested being born in Berlin" -- so just to be clear, is it inadmissible *in general* in German to make a factually false statement ("Ich bin Berliner", "We are all Hrant Dink") with the intent of expressing solidarity? Or is it that "Ich bin Berliner" means "I was born in Berlin", and "Ich bin ein Berliner" means, "I am a resident of Berlin", and the latter is the better way to express solidarity?

Comment: @SteveJessop There isn't an actual difference in meaning. But there is a subtle difference in how it may be received. "Ich bin Berliner" (omitting the article) is everyday speech, while "Ich bin ein Berliner" suggests "I am one of you (the inhabitans of Berlin)" (because 'ein' also means 'one'). Both mean "Berlin is my (adopted) home city"

Comment: In the speech, after the first time that he says "Ich bin ein Berliner", he next says "I appreciate my interpreter translating my German!"  https://millercenter.org/the-presidency/presidential-speeches/june-26-1963-ich-bin-ein-berliner-speech So, I'm wondering how the German translator translated "Ich bin ein Berliner".

Comment: @mickburkejnr, unexpected yet obligatory Mitchell&Webb reference: https://youtu.be/wJs3Tsx-3Ak?t=7s

Comment: Do you stress *ein* in speech?

Comment: @KarlKastor I certainly wouldn't interpret the difference like that; The difference between omitting the adjective or not is more a matter of familiarity than anything else; Leaving the adjective off is a colloquialism, albeit a very common on. In this instance the meaning would still have come across the same if he omitted the 'ein'; This version is just slightly more stuff while being also slightly more 'correct'.

Comment: @fredsbend No. You would stress "ein" if it was clear that you are Berliner and you want to say you are not a special Berliner, but just one of them. And I agree with the people who say there isn't any objective difference in meaning between the version with and without "ein". Maybe there is this slight subjective hint of a difference, but nothing more. I wouldn't have thought of it. And while I'm no native speaker, I've been learning German since I was 6 years old and spent lots of time in Germany.

Comment: @SteveJessop: and also, "Ich bin ein Berliner" sounds much, much more pleasant, forceful and generally well-rounded than "Ich bin Berliner". He *was* great at rhetorics after all. I'm pretty sure people would have "gotten" the "Ich bin Berliner" as well, but it would have sounded much less impressive.

Comment: The term "ein Berliner" is much more familiar to all Germans as referring to the doughnut.  While it's not wrong to say "Ich bin ein Berliner" to refer to oneself as a person from Berlin, it's understood that people gravitate to the familiar much quicker.  Adding an unusual accent into the mix, along with a large audience, it's comical but not wrong.  A parallel in English might be when George W. Bush said "I am the decider"; many laughed because it's an unfamiliar sound coming from a person known to exhibit poor speech and/or language patterns. In the end, however, it was deemed to be correct

Comment: Lastly, the reason people tend to say "Ich bin Berliner", rather than preceding the Object with an Artikel is either out of habit or to avoid that confusion.

Comment: @Szymon  I love M&W, and that sketch highlights how some words like Frankfurter sound different to the English ear.

Comment: As being born in Berlin and having been lived all my life in Berlin I don't see a difference between the two versions and feel that both "Ich bin Berliner" and "Ich bin ein Berliner". Neither of those implies that the Person was born in Berlin. A person who lived a few years in Berlin can say either of those without implying that they were born in Berlin.

Comment: Isn't it just the same as "I am American" vs. "I am an American"? Remember 9/11, after which you'd hear people use variations of "Today, we're all Americans."

Comment: @ILMostro_7: To make it clear: the sentence/speech was not comical or awkward. It's a perfect german sentence.

Comment: @JimmyB Note that your example (like JFK's) is distinguishing between noun and adjective -- it's like "I am Canadian" (i.e. I can be factually classified as Canadian), versus "Today I am a Canadian" (I am an honorary Canadian, in Canada, and with Canadians).

Comment: Biased source. In Bavaria, they still make fun of this

Comment: In bakeries around here (southwestern Germany) they also have a cookie called an [Amerikaner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_and_white_cookie).  So far, whether I tell someone "Ich bin Amerikaner" or "Ich bin ein Amerikaner", no one has mistaken me for a cookie.

Answer (score 116):

**No.**

The Berliners (people) do not call berliner (jelly doughnut) a "Berliner", they call it *Pfannkuchen* (which - curious part here - stands for a pancake in some other parts of Germany). So even if JFK wanted to call himself a jelly doughnut, saying "ich bin ein Berliner" would not have achieved this goal - the Berliners wouldn't have understood it that way.

> There is a widespread misconception, but only outside of
>   German-speaking countries, that Kennedy made an embarrassing mistake
>   by saying Ich bin ein Berliner. By not leaving out the indefinite
>   article "ein," he supposedly changed the meaning of the sentence from
>   the intended "I am a citizen of Berlin" to "I am a Berliner" (a
>   Berliner being a type of German pastry, similar to a jelly doughnut).
>
> The indefinite article is frequently omitted in German when
>   speaking of an individual's profession or residence but is in any case
>   used when speaking in a figurative sense. Since the President was not
>   literally from Berlin but declaring his solidarity with its citizens,
>   "Ich bin ein Berliner" was the only way to express what he wanted to
>   say.
>
> Furthermore, although the word "Berliner" is used for a jelly
>   doughnut in the north, west and southwest of Germany, it is not used
>   in Berlin itself or the surrounding region, where the usual word is
>   "Pfannkuchen."

[Further reading on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ich_bin_ein_Berliner#.22I.27m_a_doughnut.22_urban_legend)

Comment: Of course, if someone said "I am a Hamburger" to show solidarity with the people of Hamburg, Americans would find it amusing.

Comment: And, in Vienna a hot dog is called a Frankfurter, and in Frankfurt it is called a Wiener.

Comment: This wouldn't make sense anyway. "jelly doughnut" and "person from Berlin" are both singular nouns. Why would adding an article change the meaning?

Comment: @sgroves Because the boundary between nouns and adjectives are slippery. And when you see a noun used in a context where you expect an adjective, you're more likely to think the noun is being misused as an adjective. So if you heard someone say "I am a Hamburger" you think they're food. But if they say "I am Hamburger" you think, "It's unusual for a person to be food, it's more likely they thought 'Hamburger' was an adjective meaning 'from Hamburg'."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That doesn't make any sense. "I am a Hamburger", with a capital H, can only mean one thing in English. "I am Hamburger" is just plain _wrong_.

Comment: Maybe this comment is for the German forum but, shouldn't it be "einer Berliner"?

Comment: @Miguel no, _“einer”_ doesn't make sense here unless you add the city of origin as a predicate, i.e. _“ich bin einer aus Berlin”_ would mean “I'm someone from Berlin”. That would sure avoid the culinary ambiguity, but it would be rather awkward too. Technically, _“ich bin einer der Berliner ist”_ (I'm somebody who is Berlin-inhabitant) would also be possible, but nobody would say that.

Comment: @sgroves in a speech you don't hear the capital letters.

Comment: I can confirm this answer. As a person born (and living) in Berlin, I've said on several occasions "Ich bin ein Berliner". And the jelly donut is not called "Berliner" here, maybe except in national bakery chains.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann That's true, but my point still stands.

Comment: Like, "I am a Danish"?

Comment: @sgroves but that distinction doesn't work in Grman, where capitals are used for all nouns

Comment: The *pancake* thing isn't any more wierd than *biscuit* or *flapjack* in English. Or sticking closer to the original question, *jelly* (it would be a *jam doughnut* in Britain, where *jelly* is what's known as *Jello* in the USA, or something similar consistency)

Comment: @sgroves "I am Danish." "I am _a_ Danish." I'd say that adding an article changes the meaning there, no?

Comment: Also a  "Pfannkuchen" is (traditionally) not filled with jelly (which according to Wikipedia is made from jellfied fruit juice) but with jam (i.e. including solids from the fruit). So this very stupid (and alas unkillable) joke is wrong even on culinary detail.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: well, we usually don’t use the word Berliner for that type of food, but we know the meaning it has in other parts of Germany and understand the jokes about this. But anyway, inserting “ein” doesn’t change the meaning of “Berliner”, it’s a noun in either case and it has the two meanings in either case. And we assume the location when it appears in the speech of a politician, unless the *context* suggests otherwise, i.e. if he said “ich esse [einen] Berliner”, we would assume the food, and “einen” only suggests an amount, when inserted, not a different meaning.

Comment: @DaveSherohman Only in English. The German sentences "Ich bin Däne." and "Ich bin ein Däne." are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Indeed a jelly doughnut is called a Pfannkuchen in Berlin. This means pancake in the rest of Germany. I asked my Berliner brother-in-law, who is a baker, and had just brought us some, what Berliners say when they want a pancake, and the answer is Eierpfannkuchen, i.e. egg pancake.

Comment: @JWT Unlike with _Berliner_, there are different noun and adjectives for demonyms of Denmarkians: “I am Danish” (adjective) but “I am a Dane” (noun), in the same way that you can be British or a Brit, but you cannot be ‘a British’. _Danish_ as a noun only means the pastry, not the citizen (essentially the opposite of the local meaning of _Berliner_).

Comment: @Miguel No, the singular masculine indefinite nominative pronoun is "ein". Ein Berliner.

Comment: @Random832 Similarly, both berliners and spandauers are types of Wieners (_wienerbrød_) in Copenhagen, whereas in Vienna (I think—at least in some parts of the Germanosphere) they would be Copenhageners (_Kopenhagener_). And of course, in most English dictionaries, the definition of a wiener is “a frankfurter”…

Comment: @SebastianRedl - I would imagine the Germans have a term different that "Däne" for the pastry known in English as a "Danish."  Is that correct?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: They are called "Plunder" or "Kopenhagener (Gebäck)".

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I think "jelly" is the American word for "jam", just as "donut" is the American word for "doughnut".

Comment: @Michael Kay "Jelly" and "Jam" are generally considered different things in the US.  Jam is more like preserves, and Jelly is more like Jello (brand name for a gelatin based dessert/snack).  They are very similar though.  It basically comes down to how finely the fruit/juices are strained.  If you end up keeping most of the fruit solids, you end up with Jam.  If you strain most of the solids out then you end up with Jelly.  So EikePierstorff has the right idea on that one.  You are correct that "donut" is the common American spelling for "doughnut".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63008/discussion-on-answer-by-common-guy-did-jfk-call-himself-a-jelly-donut-in-his-fam).

Comment: @MichaelKay - For Americans "jam" and "jelly" are, usually, slightly different things. Jam is made from the whole or mashed fruit, and can contains chunks of fruit. Jelly is more made from extracted juice, and is very smooth and homogeneous, though I've never been able to tell the difference between the grape versions of each.

Answer (score 2):

[Assuming that at the time it would be almost appropriate to guess that roughly as many people present understood the English parts as well the Latin bit](https://books.google.com/books?id=zMzuMLHFKN4C&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&#v=onepage&q&f=false): Yes, it is perfectly possible that the lack of (language) context might have lead to the interpretation of jelly donut. But this would be a really clueless minority.

> [Today a note card written in Kennedy's handwriting still counts among the most cherished possessions at Berlin's Kennedy museum. Without it, the people of Berlin might never have figured out what the president was actually trying to say. In red ink and with phonetic spelling scrawled across the page, it reads: "Ish bin ein Bearleener."](https://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/berliners-remember-kennedy-visit-to-the-divided-city-a-906241-2.html)

Given the larger context of a political speech relating to the wall, the whole situation within the city, the surrounding press coverage, and the fact that in Berlin itself a "Berliner" is not called a "Berliner" it should have been very clear to everyone, so that this misinterpretation would be highly unlikely.

> [Also, as with so many things in life, context matters! The speech was delivered in Berlin in front of 450,000 people, most of whom I would assume were probably Berliner (no ‘s’ in the plural). It is true that a Berliner is a jam doughnut, but only in certain parts of Germany is it actually called a Berliner. Funnily enough, it isn’t in Berlin. There, it is referred to as a Pfannkuchen (pancake), whereas it’s called Krapfen in southern parts of Germany and Austria. So if JFK had said ‘Ich bin ein Pfannkuchen’, there probably wouldn’t be any room for speculation, but I think we can all agree that it’s pretty clear that he didn’t mean to call himself a pastry.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628211310/http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/11/day-jfk-not-call-jam-doughnut/)

This rather lengthy preamble of material already answered here in principle is only recapitulated again because no-one seems to bother answering the second part of the question: "and did they laugh?"

Some of the reactions would be called joyous, sure. Then again 'laughing' does not really fit this almost frantic reaction, shown here in a colour video:
["Ich bin ein Berliner - John F. Kennedy's visit to Germany in 1963"](https://youtu.be/zdXXkppRLEc?t=425)

> [Instead, he made it on the steps of the town-hall of the Berlin suburb of Schoneberg. Something like 400,000 people gathered in the square as he spoke.
>   And they erupted at the line which resonated round the world. He had been toying with the phrase for some weeks before. He had discussed it with his main speech writer and with people drafted in to help him with his Boston-drawl German pronunciation, which, it is generally agreed, was pretty poor.](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-23029697)

Kennedy himself didn't seem to have any concerns over the reaction he met:

> [The reaction of the crowd listening to Kennedy address them in front of West Berlin's City Hall was so overwhelming that, on the plane leaving Germany, he remarked to his aide, Ted Sorensen, who had written most of his speech, "We'll never have another day like this one as long as we live."](https://edition.cnn.com/2013/06/18/opinion/mills-jfk-berlin-speech/index.html)

So, despite the general difficulties the crowd present will have had to really understand *everything* he said and meant on a word by word basis, the reaction of the crowd indicates that the one part they surely understood best they also really understood in the way it was intended.

The origin of this whole misconception seems to be a  relatively recent one:

> That a former President of the United States should have made
>   such a fool of himself was too good a story to go unnoticed by the media. It was first presented to a national audience by Newsweek early in 1988 when the magazine printed a letter written by one Kenneth O'Neill of Danbury, Conn.: "To the Germans ['Ich bin ein Berliner'] meant 'I am a jelly doughnut'." Not long thereafter, the New York Times featured an entire article entitled "I Am a Jelly-Filled Doughnut." After telling the story, the author added his own embellishments claiming that the Berliners "tittered among themselves" when they heard the President's proclamation. […]
>   Of course, no one "tittered"or "chortled"; the situation was too tense for the Berliners to be amused. What is more, every native speaker's Sprachgefühl will tell that "Ich bin ein Berliner" is not only correct but the one and only correct way of expressing in German what the President intended to say.[…]

And the support of the natives *before* delivering the speech should clear up all possibilities of a screw-up:

> Both sentences had been translatedinto German by the man to whom Kennedy gave credit earlier in his address: Robert Lochner, son of Associated Press correspondent Louis P. Lochner, who grew up in Berlin and received his Abitur from the Dahlem Wald-Gymnasium. Lochner has provided valuable insights into how the history-making phrase found its place in the President's address: "It was only a few minutes before the address was to be delivered. When we walkedup the stairs in the city hall, Kennedy took me aside and asked me what 'I am a Berliner'and 'Let them come to Berlin' were in German. I wrote it down for him. He then disappeared into the office of Willy Brandt." Indeed Brandt, in his autobiographic  "Begegnungen und Einsichten", reports that Kennedy practiced the German words "while taking a breather in my office."' It was here that he wrote the quasi-phonetic version of the German sentences on his note cards. Immediately before the speech, on his way from the Senate Assembly room to the Rathaus balcony he again asked Klaus Franke, Brandt's personal adviser, to practice "Ich bin ein Berliner" with him.
>  
>   With this array of native support, it is obvious why the President's German grammar could not be wrong. But what about the claim that the audience misunderstood the phrase because in German the word Berliner can denote a 'jelly-filled doughnut'? This, of course, is total nonsense. In all languages, listeners derive the meaning of homonyms from the context in which they appear.
>   Seen in this light, those American colleagues who found fault with the grammar of Kennedy's statement can hardly be accused of unprofessional negligence. In the absence of help from the handbooks, it does indeed require the Sprachgefühl of a native speaker to declare John F. Kennedy's "Ich bin ein Berliner" to be correct both grammatically and semantically.
>   (Quoted from [Jürgen Eichhoff: "'Ich bin ein Berliner': A History and a Linguistic Clarification", Monatshefte, Vol. 85, No. 1 (Spring, 1993), pp. 71-80](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30153239?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents))

A small detail about 'laughter' needs clarification though.
In [John F. Kennedy: "Ich bin ein Berliner (I am a 'Berliner')" delivered 26 June 1963, West Berlin](https://americanrhetoric.com/speeches/jfkberliner.html), you get a full transcript of the speech. And in the [linked youtube video for that](https://youtu.be/hJNM0C-7lPk?t=90) you can hear that shortly after he said the words in question which are met with jubilation he also cracks after some attempts a little joke:

> Today, in the world of freedom, the proudest boast is "Ich bin ein Berliner." …
>   **I appreciate my interpreter translating my German.** (emphasis added)

*Only that joke got a bit of a laugh* after both Kennedy and the translation was met with bravo cheers and clapping. [An impression of the effect *with* the translator can be heard here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304203539/https://www.lmz-bw.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Medienbildung_MCO/mp3s/kennedy_rede.mp3) (but alas with the crucial first part containing the joke missing). But note that not even the translator deems it necessary to alter the phrase in question in any way.

**tl;dr**
Neither before, nor during and not after the speech did any German understand this quote as a funny mistake. As also shown by the absence of laughter at him. The theory about this error being possible at all originated apparently *long* after the fact from a non-native speaker.

Comment: "Assuming", "almost appropriate", "guess", "roughly", "possible", "should have been", "unlikely". Rather than speculating what you think was likely happened, a better answer would have some actual evidence based on the actual event or expert analysis of the event. If you just want to show the crowd reaction was not laughter via the video, focus on that.

Comment: The last link is broken.

Comment: The [first known occurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ich_bin_ein_Berliner#%22I'm_a_doughnut%22_urban_legend) of the myth is before the 1988 Newsweek letter: Len Deighton's 1983 novel *Berlin Game*, from which it propagated to the *New York Times* review of the book and presumably entered the American popular consciousness. Whether Deighton himself or the book's unreliable narrator actually intended the claim to be taken seriously is unknown.